# How to choose between two replicated quantities in R

Tags: r, dataframe

This is a simplified example.
I have a data frame with two variables like this:

```
a <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,6,7,4,5,5,8)
b <- c(5,10,4,2,8,4,6,9,12,3,7,4,1,7)
D <- data.frame(a,b)
```

As you can see, there are 8 values for `a` but they have replicated, and my data-frame has 14 observations. I want to create a data-frame which has 8 observations in which the `a` quantities are unique, and the `b` values are the minimum of choices, i.e., the result should be like:

```
  a  b
1 1  4
2 2  2
3 3  6
4 6 12
5 7  3
6 4  7
7 5  1
8 8  7
```

Comment: Pick your favorite method from the FAQ [How to sum a variable by group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/903061), and then replace `sum` with `min` to get the minimum instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using R base approach:

```
> D2  <- D[order(D$a, D$b ), ]
> D2  <- D2[ !duplicated(D2$a), ]
> D2
   a  b
3  1  4
4  2  2
7  3  6
11 4  7
13 5  1
9  6 12
10 7  3
14 8  7
```

Comment: This solution certainly works for this very particular question, but I would advise readers to look at other solutions posted below that use `aggregate`, `data.table`, or `dplyr`/`tidyverse` functions as those solutions allow you to easily switch out the function of interest (i.e., `sum` instead of `min`).

Comment: I believe it's inefficient and convoluted to sort and remove duplicates when it's the most basic case of aggregation.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I just posted an alternative different from `aggregate`, because there are other answers using `aggregte`. This is only another point of view.

Comment: That's fair, and I didn't downvote, but I think it was worth mentioning

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to do it with base R:

```
#both lines do the same thing, pick one
aggregate(D$b, by = D["a"], FUN = min)
aggregate(b ~ a, data = D, FUN = min)
```

Here's how to do it with data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(D)
D[ , .(min(b)), by=a]
```

Here's how to do it with tidyverse functions:

```
library(tidyverse) #or just library(dplyr)
D %>% group_by(a) 
  %>% summarize(min(b))
```

Comment: Using formulas notation  is a  more readable version of `aggregate` : `aggregate(b~a, data=D, FUN = min)`

Comment: @JilberUrbina - You're probably right.  I loath `aggregate()`.  It's clearly a function written without data.frames in mind, yet it's a common thing to do with data stored in a data.frame.

Answer (score 1):

A `base R` option would be

```
aggregate(b ~ a, D, min)
```

Answer (score 0):

`library (dplyr)`

`D<-D %>% group_by(a) %>% summarize(min(b))`

Comment: Or: library(dplyr); D %>% group_by(a) %>% summarize(min(b))

Comment: This will still have duplicated rows if there is a tie for the min. The `summarize` method is better to avoid this problem.